# dpkg: error processing package libc-bin

Tags: ubuntu, update, upgrade

When I run `sudo apt-get upgrade`, I get:

> /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu: Bus error (core dumped) dpkg: error processing package libc-bin (--configure):  subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 135 Errors were encountered while processing:  libc-bin E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Then I executed:

```
 sudo apt-get --reinstall install libc-bin
```

But got:

```
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already                                                                                                        Errors were encountered while processing:
 libc-bin
 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
 adobe-flashplugin
 adobe-flash-properties-gtk
 libegl1-mesa:i386
 libgl1-mesa-dev:i386
 libwayland-egl1-mesa:i386
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Remove or reinstall does not work.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Bus error indicates failing hardware. Try running a memtest.

Comment: Tried running memtest, passed successfully but didn't change outcome.